# Unsupported Relationship Type

Tags: xml, go

I am trying to make a simple program that will read text inside the paragraphs of a slide and simply print in out in the console.

I've don some browsing and found solutions but only for Word Documents and nothing specifically for PPTX files

This is the error:

```
[  DEBUG ]   2
[  DEBUG ]   DocumentVersion.ID = 0
[  DEBUG ]   Getting Raw Text
2019/05/21 01:54:22 unsupported relationship type: http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/presProps tgt: ppt/presProps.xml
2019/05/21 01:54:22 unsupported relationship type: http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/viewProps tgt: ppt/viewProps.xml
2019/05/21 01:54:22 unsupported relationship type: http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/tableStyles tgt: ppt/tableStyles.xml
slide
slide
slide
&{0xc00021f380 <nil> <nil>}
&{<nil> 0xc000289f28 <nil>}
```

This is a code snippet

```
if *f == f.PPTX() {
        pres, _ := presentation.Open("/Users/asus/Desktop/test.pptx")
        buf := ""
        _ = buf
        for _, slide := range pres.Slides() {
            fmt.Println("slide")
            for _, box := range slide.PlaceHolders() {
                fmt.Println(box.Index())
                // for _, para := range box.Paragraphs() {
                //  fmt.Println(para)
                //  fmt.Println("para")
                // }
            }
        }
    }
```

It loops at the pres.Slide() successfully though

Can someone give me a detailed explanation regarding that error and how I can fix that? I think the only problem is it can't open the file.

Comment: We can't give you a detailed explanation about an error presumably coming from the `presentation` package when we don't know the origin of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try unioffice? See the [sources](https://github.com/unidoc/unioffice/blob/master/presentation/open.go#L24)

Example of [usage](https://github.com/unidoc/unioffice/blob/master/_examples/presentation/use-template/main.go#L14)